# How to append two JSON into one JSON, Python Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, json, flask

I have a python flask  3.4 web service.

I also have MYSQL database with two tables, table 1 and table 2.

For the table 1, I am fetching data to my browser in a JSON format.

For the table 2, I need a static table so, I managed to convert the table to XML in the memory, which is static now. I have also managed to fetch the values in a JSON format from the static XML.

Now, I want to append both the JSON values to one JSON, how can I achieve this. 
I have already tried with the following code:

```
event=getxml() //table 1-  XML
description = event.getname('921') 
xmlvalue = jsonify (description) 
conn=pymysql.connect(host='',user='',password='',db='') // table 2 - MYSQL
a=conn.cursor()
sql='SELECT logseq, logcode FROM `table2`Where Event_code = 921 '
a.execute(sql)
row_headers=[x[0] for x in a.description]
data = a.fetchall()
json_data=[]
for result in data:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
jsonvalue = json.dumps(json_data)
return (jsonvalue,xmlvalue)
```

But this is not working, instead throwing me this error

```
TypeError('Invalid status argument',)
```

Can someone please help me with this, thanks

Comment: where exactly is that error raised?

Answer (score 0):

how about using `jsonify` ? you can import from flask, add your data to array and append your array to jsonify.

**example**

```
from flask import jsonify
    for text, predicted in zip(data, predictions): //iterate data
            result = [your data here]    
    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried jsonify but its not working, still the same result.